# JAR file runs on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, vaadin

I have created a JAR file on Maven. This application contains Spring Boot and Vaadin. I can run it on Windows. When I try to run on Linux, it says the Tomcat can't start.

I was wondering if it's a problem with OpenJDK because this is the only difference I see now. On Windows I use Oracle JDK 8.

I tried to run on AWS, Docker, Ubuntu. Same result.
Windows 10 - OK.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at no.safe4.dynamodbcsvui.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes!/:1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [dynamodb-csv-ui-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [dynamodb-csv-ui-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [dynamodb-csv-ui-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [dynamodb-csv-ui-1.0.jar:1.0]
```

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:110) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:: command not found

Comment: This is an incomplete stack trace. There should be a `caused by` section that shows why Tomcat failed to start.

Comment: Which version of Vaadin?

Comment: Added the complete stack trace. It's Vaadin 14.1.21.

Comment: Is tomcat already running on 8080 on those machines ? If so try a different port. It's hard to tell from your stack trace what is happening.

Comment: Is it a production build or a development build?

Comment: There are no applications running on 8080, I also tried other ports. It's production build.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem/solution:

1) Added debug=true to application.properties

2) After run I found it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running project in development mode with no access to folder...
```

Build project in production mode instead, see https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html

3) On Vaadin GitHub, there is a way to create the JAR file in production:

```
mvn clean package -Pproduction
```

That solved the problem and the application is running.